# Error when trying to connect to SQL database

Tags: python, sql, pymssql

I am trying to make a connection with my SQL database using python pymssql but when I run this code:

```
server = getenv("DESKTOP-O7QRHV2\SQLEXPRESS")
user = getenv("DESKTOP-O7QHRV2\John")
password = getenv("Password")
database = getenv("eerc")

print(server, user, password, database)
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, database)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM constructors")
row = cursor.fetchone()

conn.close()
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
>
> Unclosed client session
>
> client_session: aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x00000269E1804358>

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your select returns 0 row. You should do a check on the return value of fetchone before trying to iterate it.

You can try to print(row) to see if your query return some data or None for no more data.